# Keras: IndexError: tuple index out of range when loading custom model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have [an .h5 model](https://gist.github.com/duhaime/8029e424e06e861dfc6182108d36a4ce/raw/43b11c029994951dc4464847f19c59e6c8c260bc/encoder.h5) that was built with `tensorflow==1.13.1` and `Keras==2.2.4` on a host to which I don't have access. I'm trying to load that model using `keras.models.load_model` as follows:

**model.py**:

```py
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np

encoder = load_model('encoder.h5')
encoder.summary()
```

This throws a stacktrace that points to a source file (`implicit_delta.py`) I cannot open:

```
Duhaime:web doug$ python model.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0620 09:18:29.064763 140735739011968 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:517: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

W0620 09:18:29.130089 140735739011968 deprecation_wrapper.py:119] From /Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4138: The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 8, in <module>
    encoder = load_model('../pose-enc-raymond.h5')
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 225, in _deserialize_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 458, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1032, in from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 991, in process_node
    layer(unpack_singleton(input_tensors), **kwargs)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 457, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/doug/anaconda/envs/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 687, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "/home/cshimmin/jupyter/dance/implicit_delta.py", line 95, in <lambda>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I have tried installing other versions of tensorflow and keras but so far haven't had luck working around this. Is there any trick I can do to figure out how to load this model? Any suggestions or hacks are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8079) helped me realize I needed to load the model using the version of python that was used to create the model:

```
conda create -n 3.7.3 python=3.7.3
conda activate 3.7.3
```

Then pip install everything and the model will boot!